# puppet client server connection refused when I use puppet kick

Tags: puppet

I have very strange problem. I set up puppet client on several servers but have problem with one of them. 
When I invoke:

```
root@www ~ # puppet agent --server puppetmaster.domain.ltd --test 
notice: Ignoring --listen on onetime run
info: Caching catalog for puppetclient.domain.ltd
info: Applying configuration version '1326444431'
notice: Finished catalog run in 3.15 seconds
```

everything works ok.
New changes are applied to system.

When I try to pull changes to client from server:

```
root@www ~ # puppet kick puppetclient.domain.ltd
```

I got errors on client's syslog:

```
Jan 15 14:01:23 www puppet-agent[20903]: triggered run
Jan 15 14:01:24 www puppet-agent[20903]: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Connection refused - connect(2)
Jan 15 14:01:24 www puppet-agent[20903]: Using cached catalog
Jan 15 14:01:24 www puppet-agent[20903]: (/Stage[main]/Cronapt/File[/etc/cron.daily/cronapt]) Could not evaluate: Connection refused - connect(2) Could not retrieve file metadata for puppet:///cronapt/cronapt: Connection refused - connect(2) at /etc/puppet/modules/cronapt/manifests/init.pp:7
Jan 15 14:01:24 www puppet-agent[20903]: (/Stage[main]/Nagios/File[/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/]) Failed to generate additional resources using 'eval_generate: Connection refused - connect(2)
Jan 15 14:01:24 www puppet-agent[20903]: (/Stage[main]/Nagios/File[/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/]) Could not evaluate: Connection refused - connect(2) Could not retrieve file metadata for puppet:///nagios/usr/lib/nagios/plugins: Connection refused - connect(2) at /etc/puppet/modules/nagios/manifests/init.pp:27
Jan 15 14:01:24 www puppet-agent[20903]: (/Stage[main]/Nagios/File[/etc/nagios/nrpe.cfg]) Could not evaluate: Connection refused - connect(2) Could not retrieve file metadata for puppet:///nagios/etc/nagios/nrpe.cfg: Connection refused - connect(2) at /etc/puppet/modules/nagios/manifests/init.pp:18
Jan 15 14:01:24 www puppet-agent[20903]: (/Stage[main]/Nagios/Exec[/etc/init.d/nagios-nrpe-server reload]) Dependency File[/etc/nagios/nrpe.cfg] has failures: true
Jan 15 14:01:24 www puppet-agent[20903]: (/Stage[main]/Nagios/Exec[/etc/init.d/nagios-nrpe-server reload]) Skipping because of failed dependencies
Jan 15 14:01:24 www puppet-agent[20903]: (/Stage[main]/Apache2/File[/etc/apache2/conf.d/deny.conf]) Could not evaluate: Connection refused - connect(2) Could not retrieve file metadata for puppet:///apache2/etc/apache2/conf.d/deny.conf: Connection refused - connect(2) at /etc/puppet/modules/apache2/manifests/init.pp:7
Jan 15 14:01:24 www puppet-agent[20903]: (/Stage[main]/Apache2/Service[apache2]) Dependency File[/etc/apache2/conf.d/deny.conf] has failures: true
Jan 15 14:01:24 www puppet-agent[20903]: (/Stage[main]/Apache2/Service[apache2]) Skipping because of failed dependencies
Jan 15 14:01:24 www puppet-agent[20903]: (/Stage[main]/Nagios/File[/etc/nagios/cfg.d/]) Failed to generate additional resources using 'eval_generate: Connection refused - connect(2)
Jan 15 14:01:24 www puppet-agent[20903]: (/Stage[main]/Nagios/File[/etc/nagios/cfg.d/]) Could not evaluate: Connection refused - connect(2) Could not retrieve file metadata for puppet:///nagios/etc/nagios/cfg.d: Connection refused - connect(2) at /etc/puppet/modules/nagios/manifests/init.pp:37
Jan 15 14:01:24 www puppet-agent[20903]: (/Stage[main]/Apache2/File[/etc/apache2/.htpasswd]) Could not evaluate: Connection refused - connect(2) Could not retrieve file metadata for puppet:///apache2/etc/apache2/.htpasswd: Connection refused - connect(2) at /etc/puppet/modules/apache2/manifests/init.pp:31
Jan 15 14:01:24 www puppet-agent[20903]: (/Stage[main]/Apache2/File[/usr/share/phpmyadmin/.htaccess]) Could not evaluate: Connection refused - connect(2) Could not retrieve file metadata for puppet:///apache2/usr/share/phpmyadmin/.htaccess: Connection refused - connect(2) at /etc/puppet/modules/apache2/manifests/init.pp:23
Jan 15 14:01:24 www puppet-agent[20903]: Finished catalog run in 0.33 seconds
Jan 15 14:01:24 www puppet-agent[20903]: Could not send report: Connection refused - connect(2)
```

Here are configuration files at puppetclient.domain.ltd

puppet.conf

```
[main]
logdir=/var/log/puppet
vardir=/var/lib/puppet
ssldir=/var/lib/puppet/ssl
rundir=/var/run/puppet
factpath=$vardir/lib/facter
templatedir=$confdir/templates
prerun_command=/etc/puppet/etckeeper-commit-pre
postrun_command=/etc/puppet/etckeeper-commit-post
listen = true

runinterval=1800
splay=true
summarize = true
```

auth.conf:

```
path /
method find, search, save
auth yes
allow puppetmaster.domain.ltd
```

namespaceauth.conf

```
[fileserver]
allow *
[puppetmaster]
allow *
[puppetrunner]
allow *
[puppetbucket]
allow *
[puppetreports]
allow *
[resource]
allow *
```

Puppet master version 2.7.9

Puppet client version 2.7.6

Answer (score 10):

Since you're specifying `--server` when running `puppet agent`, you should put this into the client's puppet.conf file as `server = puppetmaster.domain.ltd` under the `[main]` section.  Otherwise the client will be trying to connect to the default host "puppet" when being kicked.